# MVC3 SelectListItem. Is it possible to decorate it with custom html attributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, razor

if I have something like this:

```
@{
   var cats = GetCategories();
   var selectList = from c in cats
   select new SelectListItem
   {
     Selected = (c.Id == Model.SessionCategory.Id),
     Text = c.Name,
     Value = c.Id.ToString(),
    };
  }
 @Html.DropDownList("categories", selectList)
```

The markup would be like this:

```
 <select id="categories" name="categories">
    <option value="1">Category1</option>
    <option value="2">Category2</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="3">Category3</option>
 </select>
```

And now, the question is:

**Is it possible to add additional attributes to each `<option>` tag?
I mean from the Razor template. Without jQuery workarounds?**

Comment: are you trying to add extra attributes to the `option` tag or `select` tag?

Comment: Sorry I missed that. I should've put it into single quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the most practical solution would be some jQuery or maybe something like this..

```
<select id="categories" name="categories">
    @foreach (var item in selectList) {
        <option @if (item.Selected) { <text>selected="selected"</text>} value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
    }
</select>
```

you could obviously add in attributes as needed...

Comment: Heh, I was going to do that but I tend to prefer @Html methods :) +1 for you

Answer (score 2):

By default, no. The `SelectListItem` does not contain any additional properties to add your attributes to. However, you *could* create your own `DropDownList` method or `DropDownListFor` and create your own `ListItemToOption` with a custom `SelectListItem` to add your own attributes.

But it's probably overkill.

Comment: Yeah it totally sounds like overkill. I'm rooting for jQuery if there is no other simple way to do that

Comment: I wanted to see if it was at least simple...and started to do it but there'd be so much copy/paste and modification of code to get all the functionality you'd expect from the HtmlHelpers...And...It will probably lead to errors with extensions of the same name so you'd have to rename them all...real pain :)

Comment: It would be nice to see an example of how to do your own `SelectListItem` setup.

Comment: Here's an example how you can extend SelectListItem and have your own DropDownlistFor extension method http://stackoverflow.com/a/7537628/1689049

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it:

I created my own DropDownListFor:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString TheDropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listOfValues, string placeHolder)
    {
        var model = htmlHelper.ViewData.Model;
        var metaData = ModelMetadata .FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

        var tb = new TagBuilder("select");

        if (listOfValues != null)
        {
            tb.MergeAttribute("id", metaData.PropertyName);
            tb.MergeAttribute("name", metaData.PropertyName);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(placeHolder))
            {
                var option = new TagBuilder("option");
                option.MergeAttribute("value", placeHolder);

                tb.InnerHtml += option.ToString();
            }

            foreach (var item in listOfValues)
            {
                var option = new TagBuilder("option");
                option.MergeAttribute("value", item.Value);

                var textNdata = item.Text.Split('|');

                option.InnerHtml = textNdata[0];

                if (textNdata.Length == 2)
                    option.MergeAttribute("data-name", textNdata[1]);

                if(item.Selected)
                    option.MergeAttribute("selected", "selected");

                tb.InnerHtml += option.ToString();
            }
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tb.ToString());
    }
```

Then my `SelectListItem List` is created like this:

```
    public List<SelectListItem> EmployerList
    {
        get
        {
            return Employers.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = x.EAN + "|" + x.Name,
                Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                Selected = (SelectedEmployer != null && SelectedEmployer.Id == x.Id)
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
```