# How to use object properties in dropdownlistfor option tooltips?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

After an extensive unsuccessful search I hope you guys can help me out here...

What I know: it is possible to generate tooltips for dropdownlist options through

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
       $("#someDropDownForList option").each(function () {            
       $(this).attr({ 'title': $(this).html() });
       });
    });
</script>
```

However, in my case I want to provide the users with more information on the options

```
<html>    
   <body>
      <div>
      @Html.DropDownListFor(
      m => m.SomeModelProperty,
      new selectList(Model.ListWithObjects, "Property1", "Property1"),
      new { @id="someDropDownForList"})
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

How can I use jquery to use Property2 and Property3 to construct a tooltip text for each option?

```
Property1 + " has: " + Property2 + " and " Property3
```

With kind regards,

Paul

EDIT: a solution without jquery

```
<div>
   <select id="someDropDownForList ">
   @foreach(var item in Model.ListWithObjects)
   {
   <option title="Some property is the @item.Property2: with the @item.Property3">
       @item.Property1
   </option>        
   }        
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: But what are "property2" and "property3" ? The second parameter in  `new SelectList()` is the value of the `<option>` and the third is the text...

Comment: I'm sorry for not providing that information. Model.ListWithObjects consists of objects with three (string) properties: Property1, 2 and 3. So the dropdownlist displays the string value of property 1, where I want to use the 2 remaining properties in the tooltip.

Comment: using a var ought to work... I can do something like `var Property2 = '@Model.ListWithObjects[0].Property2'`, I am not able to replace the 0 with an index of sorts (like: `var index = $(this).index();`) though... any thoughts?

Comment: Well, you can't access `Model.ListWithObjects` from client-side (javascript). You have to somehow output the data within the html. Best place would be to add some data attributes on `<option>` but the `Html.DropDownList` helper does not allow to customize the output for the `<option>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The provided helper `Html.DropDownListFor` allows only binding the `<option>` text and value through the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList` parameter (as you are doing).

The thing is that you can't access the other properties in your model from client-side javascript. Javascript does not know about your C# objects.

I think the proper way would be to generate the following HTML:

```
<select>
    <option value="ValueProperty1" title="Property1 has: Property2 and Property3">TextProperty1</option>
    ...
</select>
```

You won't even need any jquery.

How to achieve this ? I think you're better off implementing a solid solution by extending the `SelectListItem` and create a new helper method to generate the DropDownList.

The following answer does exactly this: [Adding html class tag under  in Html.DropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7536780/123127)

Comment: Thank you for this, I was wondering whether a jquery solution would be possible (also for educational purposes ;)). I had already moved to a foreach loop to at least gain the aspired functionality. I have added a snippet in the original post for completeness.