# How to add tooltip for dropdown list items in Html.DropdownListFor MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to show tool tip for the values of the dropdown list items when using,

@Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.SomeProp, 
                         new SelectList(Source, "Id", "Name"));

Here source refers to a IEnumerable collection.

I believe we don't have title property here in MVC as compared to webforms..
Can you pls suggest?

Comment: There are a couple different options, see this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647655/mvc-dropdown-option-with-title-tag-in-mvc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Little late on the response, but i'll throw my two cents in here just in case it could help answer it for someone else:

You should be able to pass the title property as an HTML attribute:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(n=>n.SomeProp,
    new SelectList(Source, "Id", "Name"),new { @Title = "Tooltip here" })
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470329(v=vs.118).aspx