# How to make list items in DropDownList to be colors instead of text in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

Suppose I have a ViewModel where there is a string field which contains name of the color. So in my DropDownList I want list items to be colors instead of mere text)) Can it be somehow done? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the standard `Html.DropDownListFor` helper doesn't allow you to define html attributes on the `<option>` element that it generates. For example your target HTML could be:

```
<select name="color">
    <option style="background-color:Red;"></option>
    <option style="background-color:Blue;"></option>
    ...
</select>
```

In order to achieve this markup you could write a custom DropDownList helper as shown in [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7537628/29407).

And to achieve even sleeker UI you could use some of the existing jQuery DropDown plugins such as [`this one`](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown).