# How to get Tooltip for selected item in DropDownListfor?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

I couldnt find an attribute "title" for DropdownListFor and was wondering how to do the same for just the selected item in the dropdownlistFor. My code is

```
               @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.objDetails.CategoryId, new SelectList(Model.objDetails.Categories, "CategoryId", "CategoryName"),  new { id = "cboCategory", style = "width:340px;"} )
```

Answer (score 1):

Source SO

The built-in DropDownList helper doesn't allow you for setting additional HTML attributes on individual options such as title. You will have to write your own custom helper if you want to achieve that. Here's one [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536631/adding-html-class-tag-under-option-in-html-dropdownlist/7537628#7537628)

Comment: hmmm... Maybe i could keep something lyk a span or div inside dropdownlist, set the value as selctedindex and and provide title for the div.