# asp.net mvc dropdownlist option disabled selected

Tags: css, html, asp.net-mvc-4, placeholder

Is there any elegant way to create something like this

```
<select>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="1">Option1</option>
</select>
```

using @Html.DropDownListFor helper in ASP.NET MVC 4?

http://jsfiddle.net/wLAt8/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately not. There is no way to add attributes to a `SelectListItem`, which is what gets rendered as an `<option>`.

You would need to extend the `SelectListItem` class, and then extend the `DropDownListFor` to use it. It is unfortunately not very straightforward... It would have been nice for there to be an `Attributes` dictionary on `SelectListItem` for this purpose.

Here is an implementation of a custom attribute being applied:

[Adding html class tag under <option> in Html.DropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536631/adding-html-class-tag-under-option-in-html-dropdownlist/)

Comment: It actually does have 'Disabled' property and 'Selected', at least in .net 5, but Hidden is not there unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way you could do it using tag helpers.

```
     <select asp-for="@Model.Orders.FruitsId" class="form-control">

                            <option value="">Select a Fruit</option>

                            @foreach (var Fruit in Model.Fruits )
                            {
                                if (barber.Name.Equals("Orange"))
                                {
                                    <option disabled="disabled" value="@Fruit.Id">@Fruit.Name </option>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <option value="@Fruit.Id">@Fruit.Name </option>
                                }


                            }
                        </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

After struggling I've done this via js function:

```
function handleSubAction(select) {
    var item = document.getElementById(select);
    item.children[0].disabled = true;
    item.children[0].hidden= true;
    return false;
}
```

and event handler in HTML:

```
 <body onload="handleSubAction('subAction');"/>
```