# @html.dropdownlistfor disable one item if condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I am doing and MVC Application and I have a DropDownListFor and I need to Disable an Item depend on Condition..

Here is my DropDownList

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.SubsidyPlanType, new SelectList(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "", "" }, { "1", "Dollar" }, { "2", "Percentage" }, { "3", "Active" } }, "Key", "Value"), new { id = "Type", @class = "form-control form-select" })
```

I need Option 3 "Active" to be disable `if condition Model.Value = "1"`

How can I disable a single Item.?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [asp.net mvc dropdownlist option disabled selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119816/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlist-option-disabled-selected) .  Admittedly this question was MVC4, but it hasn't changed in MVC5 AFAIK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following example to set `Disabled` property that indicates whether this `SelectListItem` is disabled:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.SubsidyPlanType,
      new Dictionary<string, string> { { "", "" }, { "1", "Dollar" }, { "2", "Percentage" }, { "3", "Active" } }
      .Select(d =>
      {
          return new SelectListItem() { Disabled = (d.Key == "3"), Text = d.Value, Value = d.Key };
      }),
      new { id = "Type", @class = "form-control form-select" })
```