# Html helper method for DropDownList to add title tag for each list items

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to create Html helper method to add title html attribute for each items in DropDownListFor control.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.StateId, Model.States)

 public class Model
 {
    public int? StateId {get; set;}
    public List<SelectListItem> States {get; set;}
 }

 In controller,
  Model m = new Model();
  m.States = GetStates(). This will return List<SelectListItem> of States with Value and Text.
```

Now I want to create html helper method to add title attribute for each item with text value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create on your own.

You can pull from similar implementation
[Adding html class tag under <option> in Html.DropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536631/adding-html-class-tag-under-option-in-html-dropdownlist/7537628#7537628)

Also 
give a try to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.priority, new SelectList(ViewBag.Priority, "Value", "Text"), "-- Select Priority --", new { @class = "required", title="priority" })
```