# C# to VB.Net HtmlHelper Extension Conversion Error

Tags: vb.net

I recently converted a HtmlHelper from C# to VB.Net and I’m getting an error in my razor view.  For some reason, the helper method is asking for the htmlhelper parameter in the view.  I tested the original code in C# and it works, and it does not require the first parameter.  Here’s the code:

**Original C# Extension:**

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class ExtendedSelectListItem : SelectListItem
    {
        public object htmlAttributes { get; set; }
    }

    public static partial class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
        static object GetModelStateValue(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string key, Type destinationType)
        {
            ModelState modelState;
            if (htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(key, out modelState))
            {
                if (modelState.Value != null)
                {
                    return modelState.Value.ConvertTo(destinationType, null /* culture */);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static MvcHtmlString ExtendedDropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(
            this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
            Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
            IEnumerable<ExtendedSelectListItem> selectList,
            string optionLabel,
            object htmlAttributes,
            object selectedValue)
        {
            return SelectInternal(
                htmlHelper,
                optionLabel,
                ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression),
                selectList,
                false /* allowMultiple */,
                HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes),
                selectedValue);
        }

        private static MvcHtmlString SelectInternal(
            this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
            string optionLabel,
            string name,
            IEnumerable<ExtendedSelectListItem> selectList,
            bool allowMultiple,
            IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes,
            object selectedValue)
        {
            string fullName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName))
                throw new ArgumentException("No name");

            if (selectList == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("No selectlist");

            object defaultValue = (allowMultiple) ? GetModelStateValue(htmlHelper, fullName, typeof(string[])) : GetModelStateValue(htmlHelper, fullName, typeof(string));

            // If we haven't already used ViewData to get the entire list of items then we need to
            // use the ViewData-supplied value before using the parameter-supplied value.
            if (defaultValue == null)
                defaultValue = htmlHelper.ViewData.Eval(fullName);

            // If we still don't have the value, use what was passed in
            if (defaultValue == null)
                defaultValue = selectedValue;

            if (defaultValue != null)
            {
                IEnumerable defaultValues = (allowMultiple) ? defaultValue as IEnumerable : new[] { defaultValue };
                IEnumerable<string> values = from object value in defaultValues select Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                HashSet<string> selectedValues = new HashSet<string>(values, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                List<ExtendedSelectListItem> newSelectList = new List<ExtendedSelectListItem>();

                foreach (ExtendedSelectListItem item in selectList)
                {
                    item.Selected = (item.Value != null) ? selectedValues.Contains(item.Value) : selectedValues.Contains(item.Text);
                    newSelectList.Add(item);
                }
                selectList = newSelectList;
            }
            else
            {
                selectList.Where(li => li.Selected).ToList().ForEach(li => li.Selected = false);
            }

            // Convert each ListItem to an <option> tag
            StringBuilder listItemBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            // Make optionLabel the first item that gets rendered.
            if (optionLabel != null)
                listItemBuilder.Append(ListItemToOption(new ExtendedSelectListItem() { Text = optionLabel, Value = String.Empty, Selected = false }));

            foreach (ExtendedSelectListItem item in selectList)
            {
                listItemBuilder.Append(ListItemToOption(item));
            }

            TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("select")
            {
                InnerHtml = listItemBuilder.ToString()
            };
            tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
            tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("name", fullName, true /* replaceExisting */);
            tagBuilder.GenerateId(fullName);
            if (allowMultiple)
                tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("multiple", "multiple");

            // If there are any errors for a named field, we add the css attribute.
            ModelState modelState;
            if (htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(fullName, out modelState))
            {
                if (modelState.Errors.Count > 0)
                {
                    tagBuilder.AddCssClass(HtmlHelper.ValidationInputCssClassName);
                }
            }

            tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(name));

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
        }

        internal static string ListItemToOption(ExtendedSelectListItem item)
        {
            TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("option")
            {
                InnerHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(item.Text)
            };
            if (item.Value != null)
            {
                builder.Attributes["value"] = item.Value;
            }
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                builder.Attributes["selected"] = "selected";
            }
            builder.MergeAttributes(HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(item.htmlAttributes));
            return builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
        }
    }

}
```

Original code link: [Adding html class tag under <option> in Html.DropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536631/adding-html-class-tag-under-option-in-html-dropdownlist)

**VB.Net Extension:**

```
Namespace MyNamespace

    Public Module HtmlHelperExtensions
        Sub New()
        End Sub

        <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
        Public Function ExtendedDropDownListFor(Of TModel, TProperty)(htmlHelper As HtmlHelper, expression As Expression(Of Func(Of TModel, TProperty)), selectList As IEnumerable(Of ExtendedSelectListItem), optionLabel As String, htmlAttributes As Object, selectedValue As Object) As MvcHtmlString
            ' allowMultiple 
            Return SelectInternal(htmlHelper, optionLabel, ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression), selectList, False, htmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes), selectedValue)
        End Function

        <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
        Private Function SelectInternal(htmlHelper As HtmlHelper, optionLabel As String, name As String, selectList As IEnumerable(Of ExtendedSelectListItem), allowMultiple As Boolean, htmlAttributes As IDictionary(Of String, Object), selectedValue As Object) As MvcHtmlString
            Dim fullName As String = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name)
            If [String].IsNullOrEmpty(fullName) Then
                Throw New ArgumentException("No name")
            End If

            If selectList Is Nothing Then
                Throw New ArgumentException("No selectlist")
            End If

            Dim defaultValue As Object = If((allowMultiple), GetModelStateValue(htmlHelper, fullName, GetType(String())), GetModelStateValue(htmlHelper, fullName, GetType(String)))

            ' If we haven't already used ViewData to get the entire list of items then we need to
            ' use the ViewData-supplied value before using the parameter-supplied value.
            If defaultValue Is Nothing Then
                defaultValue = htmlHelper.ViewData.Eval(fullName)
            End If

            ' If we still don't have the value, use what was passed in
            If defaultValue Is Nothing Then
                defaultValue = selectedValue
            End If

            If defaultValue IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim defaultValues As IEnumerable = If((allowMultiple), TryCast(defaultValue, IEnumerable), New Object() {defaultValue})
                Dim values As IEnumerable(Of String) = From value In defaultValues Select Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
                Dim selectedValues As New HashSet(Of String)(values, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                Dim newSelectList As New List(Of ExtendedSelectListItem)()

                For Each item As ExtendedSelectListItem In selectList
                    item.Selected = If((item.Value IsNot Nothing), selectedValues.Contains(item.Value), selectedValues.Contains(item.Text))
                    newSelectList.Add(item)
                Next
                selectList = newSelectList
            Else
                selectList.Where(Function(li) li.Selected).ToList().ForEach(Function(li) InlineAssignHelper(li.Selected, False))
            End If

            ' Convert each ListItem to an <option> tag
            Dim listItemBuilder As New StringBuilder()

            ' Make optionLabel the first item that gets rendered.
            If optionLabel IsNot Nothing Then
                listItemBuilder.Append(ListItemToOption(New ExtendedSelectListItem() With { _
                 .Text = optionLabel, _
                 .Value = [String].Empty, _
                 .Selected = False _
                }))
            End If

            For Each item As ExtendedSelectListItem In selectList
                listItemBuilder.Append(ListItemToOption(item))
            Next

            Dim tagBuilder As New TagBuilder("select") With { _
             .InnerHtml = listItemBuilder.ToString() _
            }
            tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes)
            ' replaceExisting 
            tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("name", fullName, True)
            tagBuilder.GenerateId(fullName)
            If allowMultiple Then
                tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("multiple", "multiple")
            End If

            ' If there are any errors for a named field, we add the css attribute.
            Dim modelState As ModelState = New ModelState()
            If htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(fullName, modelState) Then
                If modelState.Errors.Count > 0 Then
                    tagBuilder.AddCssClass(htmlHelper.ValidationInputCssClassName)
                End If
            End If

            tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(name))

            Return MvcHtmlString.Create(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal))
        End Function

        Friend Function GetModelStateValue(htmlHelper As HtmlHelper, key As String, destinationType As Type) As Object
            Dim modelState As ModelState = New ModelState()
            If htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(key, modelState) Then
                If modelState.Value IsNot Nothing Then
                    ' culture 
                    Return modelState.Value.ConvertTo(destinationType, Nothing)
                End If
            End If
            Return Nothing
        End Function

        Friend Function ListItemToOption(item As ExtendedSelectListItem) As String
            Dim builder As New TagBuilder("option") With { _
             .InnerHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(item.Text) _
            }
            If item.Value IsNot Nothing Then
                builder.Attributes("value") = item.Value
            End If
            If item.Selected Then
                builder.Attributes("selected") = "selected"
            End If
            builder.MergeAttributes(HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(item.htmlAttributes))
            Return builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal)
        End Function
        Private Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, value As T) As T
            target = value
            Return value
        End Function


    End Module

End Namespace
```

**C# Razor View Syntax:**

```
@Html.ExtendedDropDownListFor(p => p.filter1.propName, (IEnumerable<ExtendedSelectListItem>)ViewBag.propNames, "", new { @class = "filter1" },null)
```

**VB.Net Razor View Syntax with error:**

```
@Imports MyNamespace

@HtmlHelperExtensions.ExtendedDropDownListFor(Function(p) p.filter5.propName, CType(ViewBag.propNames, IEnumerable(Of ExtendedSelectListItem)), "", New With {.class = "filter5"}, Nothing)
```

Being that the extension method is expecting the HtmlHelper parameter, I get the following error:

> > Argument not specified for parameter 'selectedValue' of 'Public Function ExtendedDropDownListFor ...)

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Wasted about an hour on this too. In vb.net you need to pass the first parameter htmlHelper in to your extension method. In C# you don't.

@RequiredLabelFor(Me.Html, Function(x) x.EmployeeID)

Grrr vb.net!