# How to add Id and Name attributes to the options for ASP.NET MVC dropdownlist element?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Html.DropdownList() html extension in ASP.NET MVC. It is currently generating the following html.

```
<select id="MyItems" name="MyItems">
    <option value="1">Swimming</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2">Cycling</option>
    <option value="3">Running</option>
</select>
```

I would like to have Id and name attributes for each 'option' element in the the 'select` element.

Any suggestions on how I could achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you would want that?? can you explain?

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad - Our testing wants it that way so that they could run automation tests easily. They mentioned that our testing framework has hard time uniquely identifying each of those options. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: the name attribute on the option element is obsolete per the html5 spec http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html .  id is possible, for instance if you wish to search the dom to find the element, but not typically very useful since it's quite easy to get elements by value.

Comment: And you can't do it with `@Html.DropdownList()` so you would need to write you own helper.

Comment: Check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536631/adding-html-class-tag-under-option-in-html-dropdownlist/7537628#7537628

Comment: you can uniquley identify on the basis of value attrribute

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible with Html.DropdownList()

you have option that you can generate this drop down using jquery then add this id and name attribute.

This will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box as far as I can see. However, I believe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536631/adding-html-class-tag-under-option-in-html-dropdownlist/7537628#7537628) will lead you to the answer you need.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input.