# Add custom HTML data attributes to SelectListItem in MVC5 Controller or View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I suppose someone will want to mark this question as a duplicate. There are many examples of how to do what I'm needing, but for some reason I'm not getting anywhere with those examples. I get compiler errors. Also, the examples I'm seeing are for MVC3 and I'm using MVC5.

*Objective*

Add a couple of custom HTML `data-custom1` and `data-custom2` attributes to SelectListItem to render this output:

```
<option value="somevalue" data-custom1="Some Data" data-custom2="Some Data 2" >Option 1</option>
```

*Controller Action*

```
model.DropdownItems = dbProduct.MyItems
      .Select(m => new SelectListItem
      {
          Value = m.ID,
          Text = m.Name,
       => data-custom1 = m.customField1,   <=
       => data-custom2 = m.customField2    <=
      })
      .ToList();

return View(model);
```

*View*

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
      w => Model.ItemID,
          new SelectList(Model.DropdownItems, "Value", "Text", Model.ItemId),
          new { @class = "form-control text-left" }, 
          ?????????
)
```

I've seen that an HTML Helper could be created and I've tried implementing the examples, but I get varying compiler errors.

Comment: You cannot add add custom attributes using `SelectListItem` (it contains only properties for `Text`, `Value` and `Selected` (plus a couple of others in MVC-5), and to write you own class would also mean writing your own extension methods for `DropDownList()` and `DropDownListFor()` (along with new methods for `SelectList` etc). The easy way is just to pass a collection of objects to the view and use javascript to add the `data-*` attributes

Comment: @StephenMuecke The data for these attributes is not available on the frontend (at this point). I do understand you are saying to pass an object to the client containing the data values. I've tried doing a `foreach` in the View and manually creating the `<select>` options, but I couldn't get that working either.

Comment: Just pass a collection of objects containing the properties/values as a view model property (or `ViewBag` property) and you can assign that to a javascript array `var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.YourCollection);` and then use javascript to loop through it and update the option attributes. But why would you need them as `data-*` anyway?

Comment: There are 2 possibilities for the Text property depending on the setting of another control in the View. The user can change this setting and I want to update the select item's Text without making another call to the server.

Comment: In that case I would just assign the values to javascript arrays (no need to add any attributes). And just use javascript to update the html based on the selection using javascript

Comment: And just as a side not, using `new SelectList(...)` to create a 2nd `IEnumerable<SelectListIem>` that is identical to the 1st one (`Model.DropdownItems`) is pointless, as is adding the 4th parameter of in the `SelectList` constructor (which is ignored) - its just `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ItemID, Model.DropdownItems, new { .. })`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding html class tag under <option> in Html.DropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536631/adding-html-class-tag-under-option-in-html-dropdownlist)